# Magento - block caching

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

In my header.phtml I have some code that lists out products in a navigation menu. The items in the menu are actually calls to Mage::

Looking the speed of my pages, this seems to slow down page load times.

I have looked around the Magento forums etc and it seems that I could possibly cache these calls to Mage that are called in my header.

How could I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/block_cache_and_html_ouput

**EDIT**: Some more insight as well:
https://www.nicksays.co.uk/developers-guide-magento-cache/

Comment: The second link looks promising.

Comment: but i want to know list of all blocks cached